# Apache Wink integration with Swagger

Tags: spring, swagger, apache-wink, swagger-ui

I am trying to use Swagger in the existing Wink restful web services. I have done all the annotations as mentioned in the swagger documentation but now I need to integrate the rest of the stuff. E.g. configuring the swagger UI, setting up the swagger configurations during server startup etc. Can any one point me to any documentation or provide some steps to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just made a project for Apache Wink. You can find it below

https://github.com/zouzias/swagger-jaxrs-wink

I will push it to the swagger-core samples collections asap as well.